# How implement an intelligent agent in a semantic web application?

Tags: jena, semantic-web, ontology, multi-agent

I'm studying the semantic web and trying to create a application with Java.

I already have the theoretical background about Semantic Web, I have a ontology created in OWL and also know about SPARQL. I'm using Jena Framework to interact with my ontology and all works fine when I use some tutorials found in internet.

Now, I'd like to know how can I implement an intelligent agent for my application? I mean, I didn't understand what's a intelligent agent proposed in the semantic web theory. How Can I implement it? It's a class?

I found some links about the [TROPOS methodology](http://www.troposproject.org/) for create multi-agent applications, but I don't see an obvious interaction between these two things (multi-agent applications and semantic web), although I see some works linking them.

In short, How can I implement this agents? There are some [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585932/how-is-owl-actually-used-when-building-a-semantic-web-application) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254678/developing-a-semantic-web-application) here in SO, but neither is about intelligent agents.

**UPDATE**

My background:

I'm developing a web-based [CASE tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-aided_software_engineering), so I have many classes and entities about the software development process. Now, I'll try to apply some semantic web techniques to include some functions that helps the developer to deal with some tasks.

It's hard to show the specific requirements of the tool, because it's a huge project still in early stages, so I made this more general question (hoping it is not too broad for SO).

Take a example. In the tool, I have a table for software requirements in a MySQL database, I also have a requirements class in Java that works like a Java Bean for the table and a Controller class that has methods based in the table to show reports for example.
In my OWL ontology, I have the requirement class and I can use Jena to create a new individual, based in the infos retrieved from the database, but I can't use this information, because I didn't found any good tutorial to learn about how implement a intelligent agent that could, for example, analyse all requirements and define ambiguity or things like that.

The same problem occurs with all my classes. I understood the concept of a intelligent agent, but I can't understand how I can implement it.

Comment: what is the objective of the system that you want to implement? what requirements do you have? you need a clear goal do implement a meaningful system.

Comment: Thx @darlinton. I update my question with some background, but my question is purposely more general. I understood (or at least I think I did) what is an intelligent agent, but I can't find a way to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for an agent framework / programming language rather than an agent methodology. Familiarize yourself with below list before starting with methodologies.

Check out one of these:

- [JADE](http://jade.tilab.com/)
- [JASON](http://jason.sourceforge.net/)
- [2APL](http://apapl.sourceforge.net/)
- [More](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Agent-based_programming_languages)

These are all (at least partly) in java and very easy to implement together with Jena.

I'm working with Jena combined with (multi) intelligent agent systems. Let me know if I can help you in any way!

Comment: It sounds like what I was looking for. I didn't find any tutorial linking Jena with JADE before, but it seems to me that they work well together.

Comment: in most of the agent programming languages both the actions of an intelligent agent and the environment of an intelligent agent are programmed using java. You can use the jena libraries for both.